# How to include Google charts API without calling google.load()?

Tags: google-visualization, google-cdn, google-loader

The jQuery, jQuery UI and Google Maps can be loaded from Google's CDN in two ways - either by using **google.load()**:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("jquery", "1");
google.load("jqueryui", "1");
google.load("maps", "3", {other_params: "language=de&sensor=false"});
</script>
```

or by using the static **<script src="...">** tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&language=de"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Is there please the 2nd way available for [the Google charts API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/) as well?

For me only this method works:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});
</script>
```

but I can not find the URL for the 2nd way.

And I would prefer to include the Google charts API statically because it looks more straightforward to me and because of [my current problem with DataTables.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9957084/google-loader-doesnt-work-with-locally-hosted-datatables-net).

When I look at the resources using the Google Chrome console, I can see the address like

https://www.google.com/uds/api/visualization/1.0/342b7b8453344477d252440b6c1305c9/format+en,default,corechart.I.js

but I think it is a temporary one, which can expire...

Comment: This worked for me `<script type="text/javascript" src="uds_api_contents.js"></script>` and yeah you can get that file from here https://gist.githubusercontent.com/makevoid/3999915/raw/14ca8613820c3046ad248c381e3368c4d5ea59b4/uds_api_contents.js
Include this file after `jsapi`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've found an [autoloading](https://developers.google.com/loader/#AutoLoading) workaround:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1','packages':['corechart'],'language':'ru'}]}">
</script>
```

**UPDATE 2017:**

Chrome displays this warning though:

> jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1','packages':['corechart','table'],'…:22
>   A Parser-blocking, cross-origin script,
>   https://www.google.com/uds/api/visualization/1.0/84dc8f392c72d48b78b72f8a2e79c1a1/format+ru,default+ru,ui+ru,table+ru,corechart+ru.I.js,
>   is invoked via document.write. This may be blocked by the browser if
>   the device has poor network connectivity. See
>   https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5718547946799104 for more
>   details. google.loader.f @
>   jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1','packages':['corechart','table'],'…:22
>   (anonymous) @
>   jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1','packages':['corechart','table'],'…:54

Comment: @Alexander Farber:-What if i am using this:-google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['corechart', 'annotationchart', 'calendar', 'gantt', 'gauge', 'map', 'orgchart', 'sankey', 'timeline', 'treemap', 'wordtree'] });. How to write same line of code for loader.js ?

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to find this out as well - all of my searching indicates that there is no way of direct linking the charts API (which is a shame). I eventually ended up using the image charts API instead:
https://developers.google.com/chart/image/

Comment: I use Image Charts myself (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10052927/draw-a-line-above-bar-chart ) but I suspect they will be discontinued soon (Google has been quick to do that for some recent products), so I'd like to move up.