# Draw a line above bar chart

Tags: charts, bar-chart, google-visualization

In the old static image Google charts I have been producing a combined chart like this one:

[image]

It has 3 series (the bars drawn in dark green, light green and pink - on the top) and then it is overlayed by one more data serie - the blue line.

My question is: if that is possible [in the new Google charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like [Combo Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/combochart) still has documentation for columns, stacked columns and lines.